# AndroidRuntime error SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not whitelisted

Tags: android, security, whitelist

Getting this error from a modified Google app:
AndroidRuntime: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not whitelisted

E AndroidRuntime:   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2013)
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1959)

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score -7):

Fixed! Just removed the call to ReadException. App now working!

Comment: Where to remove? Can you please explain more?

Comment: How to remove the call? Is it outside the APK. I'm having this error while launching Vanced 15

Comment: It´s in the APK. You have to use apktool to disassemble and re-assemble. It's a bit of a learning curve!

Comment: Maybe you didn't install microg, the background app for vanced. Read the installation notes!

Comment: Please be more specific!

Comment: Add some info about this